# Beautiful Soup 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text' when i use list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with Beautiful soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(xx)
f = soup.find_all(xxx)
```

**then I check it:**

```
i = f[0]
print i.text
```

Result is ok, no error

**but when I use list:**

```
for i in f:
print i.text
```

**I get a error :" None Attr"..**

Comment: What is `xxx` inside the `find_all` method? And could you show us the relevant part of the HTML source?

Comment: Your loop should work. I think your problem lies somewhere else. Show us more code.